# Measurement of the Cosmological Constant

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

Is there some way to measure Lambda, the cosmological constant, independent of $H_o$,
the Hubble constant and omega_lambda, the Dark Energy density?  A standard equation for calculating Lambda, adapted from its wikipedia entry is:
$$\Lambda=3\left(\frac{H_o}{c}\right)^2\Omega_\Lambda*l_{pl}^2$$
At this site, the value of this cosmological constant is given as 2.888*10^-122 lpl^-2 .  This involves the use of two 2018 Planck Probe data figures, Ho=67.66±0.42 (km/s)/Mpc
and omega_lambda = .6889
But, as we know, there is strong discrepancy between various measures of Ho.  And some variation in the measure of omega_lambda.  Which introduces wiggle room for Lambda.
Is there an independent and possibly more direct way to measure Lambda?

1-18-2024
I just found an odd result that seems to relate to Lambda and its
dark energy density:  I took this data from wikipedia’s “Dark
Energy” entry, in its first paragraph:
“…Dark energy's density is very low: 6×10^−10 J/m^3”.
(I can’t tell where or how they got this measure)
I then took the universe age (13.82 billion years) and converted
that
to it’s “photon look-back distance”; ie: its radius minus the expansion factor.  Using Ru=13.82 billion LY= 1.3076 * 10^26 meters, allows a total universe volume Vu of 9.365*10^78 m^3 (assuming sphericity).

When I multiply 6×10^−10 J/m^3 by this Vu and convert that
energy to mass, I get a mass Mde = 6.243*10^52 kg, where
Mde is the mass equivalent of all the dark energy in our universe.
I next posit that our universe has total mass Mu = Ru*c^2 / 2G;
ie: it’s at critical density; a fair assumption.
This yields Mu = 8.816*10^52 kg.  This is close to recent
estimates of universe mass.  But the ratio of Mu / Mde = 1.412..
approximately (2)^.5.  This might mean that Mde = .707 Mu.
Ie: That omega-lambda might be .7071..or 1 / 2^.5;
within the error bounds of some of the Planck Probe data.
This may be mere coincidence, but it’s intriguing.